# Angular Material css is not working on Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material

Why is my css applied to the sliders so out of place? The others like inputs, buttons, etc,.. work fine.

This is how it should look like 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider

And this is how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CyPe.jpg "Slider"

Thanks!

Comment: imgur link is 404ing

Comment: @davidwickman oh sorry, no it works!

Comment: can you drop the code into a plunker? make sure you have the css property  `md-slider .md-focus-ring { position: absolute }`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/2snm6PawEh6FuNMIITtD I did my best but the slider won't show up. Basically i used Material Design Light for the overlay and then used Angular Material for the basic components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2snm6PawEh6FuNMIITtD) in your comment has many errors that you can see in the console.

I have created a CodePen with your markup and code and it seems to work fine with the correct files loaded - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Kgwxra?editors=1010#0)

The files below can be seen by clicking on "Settings".

CSS files

https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css
https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css

JS files

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js
https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js

You slider

```
<md-slider-container>
    <md-slider flex="" min="0" max="255" ng-model="color.red" id="red-slider">
    </md-slider>
    <md-input-container>
        <input flex="" type="number" ng-model="color.red" aria-controls="red-slider">
    </md-input-container>
</md-slider-container>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I changed the version of the angular links from 1.4.8 to 1.5.5 and now it works!